# WinAPI win32 Programming - Button not visible

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have used `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()` to determine that the button is successfully being created. However, it is not visible when I run the program.  I originally had buttons created in winMain, but found posts online stating NOT to do this, so I commented it out and added the creations in `WM_CREATE`.  Note, all ID's, etc are defined in a `resource.h` file, and `void ErrorExit()` was taken from MSDN to make using `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()` easy on a relatively new winApi programmer like me.  My code is as follows:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0900
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0900

#include <strsafe.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "resource.h"

HWND main_hwnd, tab_hwnd, tab0_hwnd, tab1_hwnd, tab2_hwnd, tab3_hwnd, tab4_hwnd;
HINSTANCE tab_hinst;
TCHAR HomePath[MAX_PATH*2], SavePath[MAX_PATH*2];
WNDCLASSEX wc;
bool success=FALSE;
MSG msg;
HWND button;
static HWND text;
TCITEM tie;
int focus = 0, NotifyCase = 0;

void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw); 
}

// Step 4: The Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                if(tab0_hwnd!=NULL)
                    button = CreateWindow("Button","Navigate to...", BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,350,42,100,25,tab0_hwnd,(HMENU)ID_B_HOME,(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(tab0_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),0);
                /*if(tab0_hwnd!=NULL)
                    button = CreateWindow("Button","Save to...", BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,350,92,100,25,tab0_hwnd,(HMENU)ID_B_SAVE,(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(tab0_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
                */HMENU hMenu, hSubMenu;

                hMenu = CreateMenu();

                hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&File");
                AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_FILE_EXIT, "&Exit");

                hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&Help");
                AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_HELP_ABOUT, "&About");

                SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
            }
            break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
            switch(((LPNMHDR)lParam) ->code)
            {
                case TCN_SELCHANGING:
                    switch(TabCtrl_GetCurFocus(tab_hwnd))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            ShowWindow(tab0_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ShowWindow(tab1_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ShowWindow(tab2_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ShowWindow(tab3_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ShowWindow(tab4_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        default:
                            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case TCN_SELCHANGE:
                    switch(TabCtrl_GetCurFocus(tab_hwnd))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            ShowWindow(tab0_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ShowWindow(tab1_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ShowWindow(tab2_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ShowWindow(tab3_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ShowWindow(tab4_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        default:
                            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_FILE_EXIT:
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_HELP_ABOUT:
                    return MessageBox(0, "This program is an alteration of...", "About", MB_OK);
                    //return DefWindowProc(hwnd2,0,0,0);
                case ID_B_HOME:
                    MessageBox(tab0_hwnd,"HERE","OKAY",NULL);
                    break;
                case ID_B_SAVE:
                    break;
                case ID_B_BLANK:
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;  
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    tab_hinst = hInstance;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Home";
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    main_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "Home",
        "The Home page",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 700, 400,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    tab_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "SysTabControl32",
        "",
        WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 681, 338,
        main_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

    tab0_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "SysTabControl32",
        "",
        WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        1, 22, 679, 315,
        tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

    text = CreateWindow("Static","Home Directory",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,0,50,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
    text = CreateWindow("Static","C:\\",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,200,50,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
    //button = CreateWindow("Button","Navigate to...", BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,350,42,100,25,tab0_hwnd,(HMENU)ID_B_HOME,tab_hinst,0);    
    text = CreateWindow("Static","Save Directory",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,0,100,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
    text = CreateWindow("Static","C:\\",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,200,100,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
    //button = CreateWindow("Button","Save to...", BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,350,92,100,25,tab0_hwnd,(HMENU)ID_B_SAVE,tab_hinst,0);

    tab1_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "SysTabControl32",
        "",
        WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        1, 22, 679, 315,
        tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

    tab2_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "SysTabControl32",
        "",
        WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        1, 22, 679, 315,
        tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

    tab3_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "SysTabControl32",
        "",
        WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        1, 22, 679, 315,
        tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

    tab4_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "SysTabControl32",
        "",
        WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        1, 22, 679, 315,
        tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

    tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tie.pszText = "Paths";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 0, &tie);
    tie.pszText = "Output";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 1, &tie);
    tie.pszText = "Parameters";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 2, &tie);
    tie.pszText = "Configurations";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 3, &tie);
    tie.pszText = "Run";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 4, &tie);

    if(main_hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(main_hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow(tab_hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow(tab0_hwnd,nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(main_hwnd);
    UpdateWindow(tab_hwnd);
    UpdateWindow(tab0_hwnd);
    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    do{
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE);
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    } while(msg.message!=WM_CLOSE && msg.message!=WM_QUIT);
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Also I'm curious about `UpdateWindow()`, do I need to call this if I'm not painting?

Answer (score 0):

At [WM_CREATE description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) we read that *the message is sent before the function returns*.

Hence `WM_CREATE` for `main_hwnd` always happens before `tab0_hwnd` is assigned.

Now let's look at your code handling `WM_CREATE`:

```
if(tab0_hwnd!=NULL)
   /* you would create the button here, but it does not happen. */
```

Now, wouldn't it be better to produce an error message if `tab0_hwnd` is `NULL`, instead of silently ignoring the error?

It's not necessarily the only problem with the code, but I won't go further without a *compilable* example.

Comment: I understand that there is a problem there but was unsure how to fix it other than adding the if statement.  What do you mean by 'compilable' btw? And may I inquire about the other problems in the code?

Comment: I mean the code which we could compile and test, especially if it's not brief and not too readable. Providing `resource.h` would probably be enough. For other problems, better create new questions -- long discussions in comments are not for that.

Comment: By the way, *if* there is anything wrong with creating buttons in `WinMain`, the same thing would be wrong with creating `SysTabControl` and everything else in `WinMain`. If you have a real reason to do it `WM_CREATE` handler, then do it *all* in that handler, that is, create tab control, tabs and buttons there in necessary order. (And doing it in `WM_CREATE` handler *doesn't mean* that you must have all the code in a giant switch. Split it out to new functions!)

Comment: I originally tried to do it all in the handler but it wasn't working. I just posted my old code in another thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365518/winapi-win32-programming-tab-control-not-showing-up).  I'm not sure what the problem with that one was.  In the current code, tabs and windows worked; however in the old code they wouldn't even show. (I added resources to the file directly so resource.h isn't required to compile the old code)

Answer (score 0):

The call to create the button in the `WM_CREATE` case of `WndProc` runs before the the `tab0_hwnd` window is created.  `CreateWindow` will not return until it calls the `WndProc` for the window class with `WM_CREATE` so the order of your code is this:

1. Create the main window: `main_hwnd`
2. Run the code in the WM_CREATE case of `WndProc`
3. Create the tab control `tab_hwnd`
4. Create the tab control `tab0_hwnd`

So you need to re-order you code so the button will not be created until after the tab has been created.

Comment: I thought the `if()` statement prevented the button from being created until `tab0_hwnd` was created? What re-ordering are you suggesting exactly?

Comment: @hherbol - what do you mean until?  The `WM_CREATE` message will only be run once so there is no until - it will never work.  I'm not sure why your button creation is ever occurring, `tab0_hwnd` should always be `NULL`.  To re-order you either need to move the button creation until after the tab is created in `WinMain` or create the tab in `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: I originally tried to do it all in the handler but it wasn't working. I posted the old code in another thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365518/winapi-win32-programming-tab-control-not-showing-up).  Not sure why it didn't work, but that's the reason I did everything initially in WinMain.

Comment: I have a quick question.  Is it possible to create a window without `WS_CHILD` and `NULL` as the parent, and then afterwards force it to be the child of another window? Or must it be declared as a child.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing`WS_VISIBLE`? It is required or you won't see it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30964396)